# Удалить местоположения с Google Map V2

Tags: android, google-maps

Здравствуйте, можно ли удалить все местоположения по умолчанию(т.е. карта была вся пустой) с Google Map?
И если можно, то как?

Comment: Что за местоположения по умолчанию? Как раз по умолчанию карта пустая.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вы имете ввиду метод `clear()`, который удаляет все маркеры, полилинии, полигоны, наложения и т.д. с карты:

```
map.clear()
```